# Creating dynamic controls for one row in a database

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dynamic

I need to be able to create dynamic radio buttons and label for each row in a dataTable. The code i have written so far produces radio buttons which are linked so i select multiple buttons at once. Rather, the radio buttons de-select upon pressing another.

```
Do
        For count = 0 To NoOfRecords - 1
            For i = 1 To NoOfRecords - 1
                Dim XCoord, YCoord As Integer
                XCoord = 269
                YCoord = 172

                Dim XCoord1, YCoord1 As Integer
                Dim Labeli As Label
                Dim RadioButtonsi As RadioButton
                XCoord1 = 269 : YCoord1 = 172

                For count1 = 0 To NoOfRecords - 1
                    Labeli = New Label
                    Labeli.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(XCoord, YCoord)
                    YCoord = YCoord + 120
                    Labeli.Text = count1 & ". " & dataTable.Rows(count1).Item(0)
                    Me.Controls.Add(Labeli)

                    RadioButtonsi = New RadioButton
                    RadioButtonsi.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(XCoord1, (YCoord1 + 20))
                    YCoord1 = YCoord1 + 120
                    RadioButtonsi.Text = dataTable.Rows(count1).Item(1)
                    Me.Controls.Add(RadioButtonsi)
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Loop Until count = NoOfRecords
```

So just to summarize, I need to be able to create controls for each row in the dataTable which aren't linked.

Comment: You can try add them to different Panel Controls, this way they won't be linked.

Comment: @Kyore Seems to have done the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, don't forget to rate the answer to help people in the future.